# build array based on a text with character delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, string, frontend

I'm having difficulty creating a generic function where an input would be a string containing a large or small volume of text and the output is an array and I'm having a lot of trouble with this complexity, but each position of the array must contain 125 characters at most and it cannot have a broken word, eg if there is any final word with which 125 character pass must be placed to the next position of the array.

Example:

Input value: `` `var text =" Lorem Ipsum is simply a text simulation of the printing and printing industry, and has been in use since the 16th century, when an unknown printer took a tray of typefaces and shuffled them together to make a type model book Lorem Ipsum survived not only five centuries but also the leap into desktop publishing, remaining essentially unchanged It became popular in the 1960s when Letraset launched decals containing passages of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently when is now integrated with desktop editing software like Aldus PageMaker." `` `

Incorrect output value: `` `[ "Lorem Ipsum is simply a text simulation of the printing and printing industry, and it has been in use since the century," "XVI, when a printer discovered a type tray and shuffled them together to make a typeface template book."] `` `

Note that the 0 position of the array has gone from 125 because of the word "century".

Correct output value: `` `[" Lorem Ipsum is simply a text simulation of the printing and printing industry, and has been in use since the "," 16th century, when an unknown printer took a tray of typefaces and shuffled them to make a book of models of "," types. Lorem Ipsum survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into desktop publishing, remaining ", ...]` ``

Comment: Split the entire string on space and then start joining back, controlling the max length of each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `.{1,125}\b` which greedily searches for between 1 and 125 characters followed by a word boundary:

```js
const regex = /.{1,125}\b/g;
var text =" Lorem Ipsum is simply a text simulation of the printing and printing industry, and has been in use since the 16th century, when an unknown printer took a tray of typefaces and shuffled them together to make a type model book Lorem Ipsum survived not only five centuries but also the leap into desktop publishing, remaining essentially unchanged It became popular in the 1960s when Letraset launched decals containing passages of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently when is now integrated with desktop editing software like Aldus PageMaker.";

console.log(text.match(regex));
```